# load listener in Store

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am using a load listener on my Store.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/source/AbstractStore.html#Ext-data-AbstractStore-event-load

```
listeners: {
    load: function (store, records, success, opts) {

    }
}
```

If **success = false**, I want to get an error message, or something from the HTTP response why it is failing.

Where can I get this information?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [exception](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-event-exception) event in the store proxy.

Check out this fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1l5m

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyJsonStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    autoLoad: true,
    storeId: 'MyJsonStore',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'non-existing-data.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        listeners: {
            exception: function (proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                // debugger;
            }
        }
    }
});
```